# how to write query in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I have one table, **User**, and in that table, I have 3 columns:

- id
- name
- email

I want to retrieve a name for a particular email by passing the email id; how would I write that hibernate query?

Comment: Are you passing *emailId* or *email* **and** *id*? And, with all respect, is it the first time you use hibernate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a criteria query:

```
Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(User.class);
criteria = criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("email", email));
List<User> results = (List<User>) criteria.list();
```

Using hql:

```
String hql = "from User where email = :email";
Query query = getSession().createQuery(hql);
query.setParameter("email", email);
List<User> results = (List<User>) query.list();
```

Comment: Thanks, Marcelo Hernández Ris.